# IList not posting back to controller correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've run into a situation where I need to be able to bulk edit and post records back to my mvc 4 controller. I have a list of my custom view model which I can correctly pass and edit on the Index view. I however cannot retreive the same list when I submit the form and try to access the list in the post method. At most, I can only get the very first record or I get null. How can I get the entire list of objects?

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models
{
    public class CheckoutViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string PTIN { get; set; }
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public Guid CartOrderId { get; set; }
        public string IRSCourseNumber { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Guid gdShoppingCartId = cmmObj.GetShoppingCartId();
        List<SitefinityWebApp.Custom.Surgent.sf_ec_cart_detail> cartdetails = new List<SitefinityWebApp.Custom.Surgent.sf_ec_cart_detail>();
        SubSiteProductRepository ssp = new SubSiteProductRepository();
        List<CheckoutViewModel> cvml = new List<CheckoutViewModel>();

        if (gdShoppingCartId != Guid.Empty && gdShoppingCartId != null)
        {
            cartdetails = DbContext.sf_ec_cart_details.Where(d => d.cart_order_id == gdShoppingCartId).ToList();
            if (cartdetails.Count > 0)
            {
                if (cartdetails.Where(c => c.need_registration2 == "true").Count() > 0)
                {
                    var webinars = LoadWebinar();
                    //WebinarViewModel wvm = new WebinarViewModel();
                    foreach (DataRow row in webinars.Rows)
                    {
                        cvml.Add(new CheckoutViewModel
                        {
                            Sku = row["sku"].ToString(),
                            Id = row["id"].ToString(),
                            Title = row["title_"].ToString(),
                            CartOrderId = gdShoppingCartId,
                            IRSCourseNumber = row["irsCourseNumber"].ToString()
                        });
                        //foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                        //{
                        //    object item = row[column];
                        //    // read column and item
                        //}
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        return View(cvml);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix="cvm.")]IList<CheckoutViewModel> cvm)
    {
        int viewmodelerror = 0;
        foreach(CheckoutViewModel c in cvm){
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //if (c.PTIN != null || c.PTIN != "")
                    //return Redirect("~/CheckOut");
            }
            else
            {
                viewmodelerror++;
                //return View(cvm);
            }
        }

        return View(cvm);
            //return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Index View:

```
    @model IList<SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models.CheckoutViewModel>
@{
    var allWebinars = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/CheckOut";
}



<div id="registration-content">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='columns medium-12'>
            <h1>Attendee Information</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='columns medium-9'>
            <div class='columns medium-12'>
                <p class='instructions'>Please complete attendee information for the following courses:</p>
            </div>

            @foreach (SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models.CheckoutViewModel cvm in Model)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(x => cvm.FirstName)
            }
            @Html.BeginForm(){
               @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
               {
                   <div class='columns medium-12'>
                       <!--FIRST PRODUCT DESCRIPTION-->
                       <div class="product-description">
                           <p class='course-link'><a href="webinars.html">@Html.DisplayFor(t => t[i].Title)</a></p>
                           <p class='small'>Accounting</p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class='columns medium-12'>
                       <form>
                           <!-- BASIC FORM LAYOUT FOR THE PAGE -->
                           <div class='row'>
                               <div class='columns medium-4'>

                                   <label>First Name @Html.EditorFor(t => t[i].FirstName)</label>
                               </div>
                               <div class='columns medium-4'>
                                   <label>Last Name @Html.EditorFor(t => t[i].LastName)</label>
                               </div>
                               <div class='columns medium-4'>
                                   <label>PTIN @Html.EditorFor(t => t[i].PTIN)</label>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class='row'>
                               <div class='columns medium-4'>
                                   <label>Email Address @Html.EditorFor(t => t[i].Email)</label>
                               </div>
                               <div class='columns medium-4'>
                                   <label>Phone Number @Html.EditorFor(t => t[i].Phone)</label>
                               </div>
                               <div class='columns medium-4'>
                                   <p>&nbsp;</p>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </form>
                   </div>
               }
            }
        </div>
        <div class='columns medium-3' id="purchase-summary">
            <!-- PURCHASE SUMMARY -->
            <h2>Summary:</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Products:</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>4</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Subtotal:</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>$906.00</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Discounts:</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>$0.00</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h4>Total:</h4>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h4>$906.00</h4>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="registration-buttons">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='columns medium-9'>
                <hr id="last-divider">
                <div class='columns medium-6 small-6'>
                    <div id="registration-back">
                        <a href="#" class="course-link arrow-left">Back</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='columns medium-6 small-6'>
                    <div class='float-right'>
                        @*<a class='button' href="@allWebinars">continue</a>*@
                        <button type="submit" id="submit">continue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='columns medium-3'>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I figured out how to fix it. I had form tags (which I didn't want) inside of the Html.BeginForm() method. In hindsight, it makes sense as multiple forms were being created but only the first one could be submitted. The working version of code is below. Thanks for your help, Stephen :)

**New View:**

```
@model IList<SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models.CheckoutViewModel>
@{
    var allWebinars = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/CheckOut";
}


@Html.BeginForm(){
<div id="registration-content">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='columns medium-12'>
            <h1>Attendee Information</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='columns medium-9'>
            <div class='columns medium-12'>
                <p class='instructions'>Please complete attendee information for the following courses:</p>
            </div>

            @foreach (SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models.CheckoutViewModel title in ViewBag.Titles)
            {
                var url = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/webinar-product-details/" + title.Sku;
                 <div class='columns medium-12'>
                    <!--FIRST PRODUCT DESCRIPTION-->
                    <div class="product-description">
                        <p class='course-link'><a href="@url">@title.Title</a></p>
                        @*@Html.HiddenFor(t => t[i].Title)*@
                        @*<p class='small'>Accounting</p>*@
                        <p class='small'></p>
                    </div>
                     <br />
                </div>
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(t => t[i].Title)
                @Html.HiddenFor(t => t[i].Type)
                @Html.HiddenFor(t => t[i].IRSCourseNumber)
                @Html.HiddenFor(t => t[i].Id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(t => t[i].Sku)
                    if(Model[i].Title == title.Title){

                <div class='columns medium-12'>
                    <!-- BASIC FORM LAYOUT FOR THE PAGE -->
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='columns medium-4'>

                            <label>First Name @Html.EditorFor(t => t[i].FirstName)</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t[i].FirstName)
                        </div>
                        <div class='columns medium-4'>
                            <label>Last Name @Html.EditorFor(t => t[i].LastName)</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t[i].LastName)
                        </div>
                        @if (Model[i].IRSCourseNumber != null && Model[i].IRSCourseNumber != "")
                        {
                        <div class='columns medium-4'>
                            <label>PTIN @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t[i].PTIN, new { @class = "ptin" })</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t[i].PTIN)
                        </div>
                        }else{
                            <div class='columns medium-4'>
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='columns medium-4'>
                            <label>Email Address @Html.EditorFor(t => t[i].Email)</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t[i].Email)
                        </div>
                        <div class='columns medium-4'>
                            <label>Phone Number @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t[i].Phone, new { @class="phone"})</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t[i].Phone)
                        </div>
                        <div class='columns medium-4'>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            }
            }
            }

        </div>
        <div class='columns medium-3' id="purchase-summary">
            <!-- PURCHASE SUMMARY -->
            <h2>Summary:</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Products:</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>4</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Subtotal:</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>$906.00</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Discounts:</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>$0.00</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h4>Total:</h4>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h4>$906.00</h4>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="registration-buttons">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='columns medium-9'>
                <hr id="last-divider">
                <div class='columns medium-6 small-6'>
                    <div id="registration-back">
                        <a href="#" class="course-link arrow-left">Back</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='columns medium-6 small-6'>
                    <div class='float-right'>
                        @*<a class='button' href="@allWebinars">continue</a>*@
                        <button class="submitButton" type="submit" id="submit">continue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='columns medium-3'>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js">

</script>
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".phone").mask("999-999-9999");
        $(".ptin").mask("99999999");
    });

</script>
```

**New Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IList<CheckoutViewModel> cvm)
    {
        int viewmodelerror = 0;
        foreach(CheckoutViewModel c in cvm){
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //if (c.PTIN != null || c.PTIN != "")
                    //return Redirect("~/CheckOut");
            }
            else
            {
                viewmodelerror++;
                //return View(cvm);
            }
        }

        return View(cvm);
            //return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Comment: Some strange things here. (1) Why do you have `[Bind(Prefix="cvm.")]`? There are no controls in the form prefixed with "cvm" (and if there were it would be "cvm", not "cvm."). (2) You have a `foreach` loop rendering `@Html.EditorFor(x => cvm.FirstName)` outside the form (and then you render it correctly inside the `for` loop using `@Html.EditorFor(t => t[i].FirstName)`. (3) Your submit button is not inside the form.

Comment: For points 1 & 2, that's the results of all the searching I did to try and help with my issue. I wasn't sure what I should be doing, so I tried to have both code paths in the project to test which one got me closer to a solution. Also, I was given this template and told to "make it work" so there could be a number of things wrong.

Comment: Get rid of the `[Bind(Prefix="cvm.")]` and the `foreach` loop. But your form does not have a submit button so you need to add `<input type="submit" />` after the `for` loop and it will post back fine. But the fact you indicated you are posting something suggest you might be using some ajax? (and if so, you need to post that)

Comment: I got it working and have updated my post to show the new code. Thanks again!